# unable to install mysql completely on debian 5.0

Tags: mysql, debian

its been a couple of days that I'm trying to install mysql on my vps which has debian 5.0 with 256mb ram. I've installed webmin also. here is the symptoms : after installing mysql using either webmin or apt-get I am trying to connect to mysql for changing root password but every time I cope with this error :

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

so I start to investigate and I understand there is no root user inside mysql database when I use :

UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE user="root";

it says 0 row affected

I reinstall mysql for several times but the same problem still exits. please help me how can I install mysql-server as well as mysql-client correctly.

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all of your advice ,
I've fixed it .
it was all about /tmp permission 
the permision of this folder shoulbe be 0777 but mine was 0775 or something like that.

regards.

Answer (score 1):

Debian mysql-server package does not set mysql root password on install, so you should be able to login from command line by simply typing `mysql` and hitting Enter.

Also, you do not need to reinstall mysql all the time, to reconfigure it you can just run `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-common`.

Comment: thats what I'm asking about when I try to login to mysql console I'll get this error :  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

also I've tried the mysqld_safe --blah blah and its not fix anything.

the real problem is with my mysql database because I get this error during starting the mysql service :
Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables..

and I almost forgot to say about my debian I've downloaded it from stacklet.com.

Comment: `Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables` is not an error. This is a legit message, telling you what mysql is doing :). Your original post said "(using password: YES)" so i assumed you are using a password.

Check `/etc/mysql/debian.conf`, it should have an account info for `debian-sys-maint` user. Use that to login into mysql and re-setting root password.

`mysql -h localhost -u debian-sys-maint -p`

Comment: so I cat the debian.cnf (there is no .conf) here is the result
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = kBB4qBvO9iMbMf6D
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr

and when I type : su debian-sys-maint I will get this error : Unknown id: debian-sys-maint 
I don't get it what is the exact problem? is it stacklet's debian problem or mine??? and just to reminind I have the same problem when I use webmin also.

Comment: Good idea about using the debian.cnf.  Instead of looking at the file you can just start the mysql client using that config file with a command like `mysql --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.

Comment: and also here is the result of what you've told me to do : 

mysql -h localhost -u debian-sys-maint -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @austin powers, I think we may have identified your confusion.  Usernames and passwords withing mysql have absolutely no relationship to users on your local system.  Your mysql root account is completely seperate from your systems root account.  Using su debian-sys-maint would not do anything useful because that is a mysql account not a system account.

Comment: @zoredach thanks man , that works!!! 
I could connect to mysql at last , so shall I start updating root password or what?

Comment: @zoredach I know what u mean but believe me this problem makes me nervous, 
anyway 
here is a new problem :
>use mysql;
>desc user;
and error is :  ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_f36_0.MYI' (Errcode: 13)

THAT's WHAT I'm talking about this the exact problem I have :((

Comment: @austin_powers: did you change anything in your config? Your mysql is trying to write to `/tmp`, which is not supposed to happen. By default mysql writes to `/var/lib/mysql`, which should belong to mysql user, NOT root.

Comment: @solefald , no I haven't change any config. /var/lib/mysql belongs to mysql user but I don't know how the heck it is going to write in tmp/  :((
how can I fix it?
I've installed the latest stable version of mysql as you know better than me debian manages them , but there are lots issues with that I believe.

Comment: This is very odd, but lets start over. `dpkg --purge mysql-server mysql-common` to uninstall it. after that do `apt-get install mysql-server` (it will install mysql-common as a dependency). After install is done do `mysql` and just hit enter. This should log you into mysql as a *mysql* root user.

Comment: @solefal I've done what u saying so just to make you and myself sure that it was a mistake by me but I'm afraid so here is the exact same problem : after trying to enter mysql : 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

please note : I haven't set any password.
I'm totally dazed now :)) :((

Comment: Perhaps you should move this discussion about issues with /tmp to a new question, instead if having a long discussion in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a command to list all the mysql packages.  `dpkg --get-selections | grep 'mysql-' | awk '{print $1}'`.  Then I would use `apt-get purge package1 package2 ... packagen` to remove.

Finally make sure everything is removed from `/var/lib/mysql/`.

Comment: so I have done what you saying , just one thing I am logged in as root user but the mysql/ owned by mysql user doesn't it make any problem?

and one more thing , for installing mysql i will use this command :
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client.

is it enough ?

regards